# Minimal API routing issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, minimal-apis, asp.net-minimal-apis

I'm creating a minimal Web API.

I have defined two routes:

```
app.MapGet("/reports/{id:Guid}", GetReportById);
app.MapPost("/reports", CreateReport);
```

with corresponding delegate handlers:

```
public static async Task<Results<Ok<ActivityReport>, NotFound, BadRequest<string>>> GetReportById(
    [AsParameters] ActivityReportingServices services,
    Guid id)
{
    if (id == Guid.Empty)
    {
        return TypedResults.BadRequest("Id is not valid.");
    }

    var activityReport = await services.Context.ActivityReports.SingleOrDefaultAsync(report => report.Id == id);

    if (activityReport == null)
    {
        return TypedResults.NotFound();
    }

    return TypedResults.Ok(activityReport);
}
```

and

```
public static async Task<CreatedAtRoute<ActivityReport>> CreateReport(
    [AsParameters] ActivityReportingServices services,
    ActivityReportForCreateDTO activityReport)
{
        
    var report = new ActivityReport() { Clients = activityReport.Clients };

    services.Context.ActivityReports.Add(report);
    await services.Context.SaveChangesAsync();

      
    return TypedResults.CreatedAtRoute(report, "/reports/{report.Id}");
}
```

The `Id` member of the `ActivityReport` class is a Guid.

My issue is that when the `CreateReport` method tries to return `TypedResults.CreatedAtRoute(report, $"/reports/{report.Id}")` I get a `"System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values"` exception.

I have tried to change the `"/reports/{id:Guid}"` route to `"/reports/{id}"` and change the `Id` parameter in `GetReportById` to a string to try and work around this issue but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

[`TypedResults.CreatedAtRoute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.typedresults.createdatroute?view=aspnetcore-8.0) requires route name, so you need to do something like the following:

```
app.MapGet("/reports/{id:Guid}", GetReportById)
    .WithName("reportsById"); // add route name

static async Task<CreatedAtRoute<ActivityReport>> CreateReport( ActivityReportForCreateDTO activityReport)
{
    return TypedResults.CreatedAtRoute(report, 
        routeName: "reportsById", 
        routeValues: new {id = Guid.NewGuid()}); // use real Guid
}
```

Otherwise use the [`TypedResults.Created`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.typedresults.created?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

> `uri` `String`
> The URI at which the content has been created.

```
// use real Guid here:
return TypedResults.CreatedAtRoute(report, $"/reports/{Guid.NewGuid()}");
```